# What is the Equation for the Batista-Costa Minimal Surface?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, applications, minimal-surfaces, derivation-of-formulae

The Batista-Costa surface is a triply periodic minimal surface. Three photos of part of the same surface are below:

[image: This is the Batista-Costa surface with many units]
[image: This is the unit surface of the Batista-Costa surface.]
[image: This highlights the unit patches of the Batista-Costa surface.]

where the first two were taken form the research paper: [The New Boundaries of 3D-Printed Clay Bricks Design: Printability of Complex Internal Geometries](https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/14/2/598)

and the third one was taken from [minimalsurfaces.blog](https://minimalsurfaces.blog/2018/12/10/the-costa-surface/)

There are many triply periodic minimal surfaces that can be found using equations that any person who has passed a trigonometry class can read and understandard (not necessarily solve). But when I Googled it and read papers that used it, as far as I can understand, they references back to the paper: [A Family of Triply Perioidic Costa Surfaces](https://msp.org/pjm/2003/212-2/pjm-v212-n2-p07-s.pdf) . This paper is not something a non-expert would be able to understand, including me. And I wouldn't know how to apply it to graph it or find the equation that it is a solution of.

Many of them have nice equations like in the LaTeX table below:

$$
\begin{array}
\hline
\textbf{Minimal Surface} & \textbf{Equation} \\
\hline
\text{Schwarz G (Gyroid)} & \cos(x)\sin(y) + \cos(y)\sin(z) + \cos(z)\sin(x) = 0 \\
\text{Schwarz P} & \cos(x) + \cos(y) + \cos(z) = 0 \\
\text{Schwarz D (Diamond)} & \sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z) + \sin(x)\cos(y)\cos(z) + \cos(x)\sin(y)\cos(z) + \cos(x)\cos(y)\sin(z) = 0 \\
\text{Scherk's Tower} & \sinh(x)\sin(y) - \sin(z) = 0 \\
\text{Neovius} & 3(\cos(x) + \cos(y) + \cos(z)) + 4\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z) = 0 \\
\text{Schoen I-WP (Batwing)} & (\cos(x)\cos(y)) + (\cos(y)\cos(z)) + (\cos(z)\cos(x)) - \cos(x) - \cos(y) - \cos(z) = 0 \\
\text{PW Hybrid} & 10(\cos(x)\cos(y)) + (\cos(y)\cos(z)) + (\cos(z)\cos(x)) - 0.01(\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)) = 0 \\
\text{Batista-Costa Surface} & ? \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: So, I had asked the web master of [minimalsurface.blog](https://minimalsurfaces.blog/2018/12/10/the-costa-surface/) and part of Indiana University, said that the above equations are not actually 100% accurate, but rather 'they are very good approximations'. I am okay will such simple 'very good approximations'.